# How to create a 3D effect with Raphael, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I know that Raphael.js is a vector graphic javascript engine.  However, I need to create cylinders in javascript and have text written on the round part of the cylinder.  The text needs to follow the surface of the cylinder, which makes a 3D like effect.

Does anyone knows how to do this with Raphael?  Otherwise, which other library should I use to achieve my goals?

Thanks in advance guys!
Steve

Answer (score 1):

The best 3d javascript library out there in my opinion is:

[Three.js by mr doob](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

Head on over and look at the examples there and view the source code. If you do fancy getting in to three.js checkout the tutorials by aerotwist:

[aerotwist tutorials](http://aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/)

**EDIT**

Three.js also has a `SVG Renderer` I found this [example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNq2a/1/)

Comment: The problem with tree.js is that it creates real 3D renders.  I just want to make it and renders it in vector graphics.  The reason behind that is that I want this to work on browsers that doesn't have webgl enabled...